# Update pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, texlive, update

I have installed `MacTex 2016` (equivalent to TexLive 2016) on my computer. That distribution contains the package `pgfplots`, but as I found out with the `\pgfplotsversion`-command, it's version 1.13.

However, the most recent version is 1.14 and as the documentation uses that version, I encounter some problems because some commands are new to the current version.

Unfortunately I was not able to update the package, by downloading it and moving it to my `texmf`-folder. Has anybody an idea on how to update from 1.13 to 1.14?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/106162)

Comment: You use TeX Live Utility (found in /Applications/TeX) to update your TeX Live distribution. There have been many updates since the release last June.

Comment: Sidenote: I think I mentioned earlier that you can use `texdoc pgfplots` in a terminal to get the documentation for the package that is installed on your system.